# How to find vertices of a $5$-dimensional simplex, where the vertices are formed by zeroes and ones?

Tags: geometry, coding-theory, combinatorial-geometry, simplex, geometry-of-numbers

I'm trying to find the vertices of a simplex in the $5$-dimensional space, where the vertices are formed by only zeros and ones, similarly to these coordinates that represent a simplex in the $7$-dimensional space:
$$\begin{align}
\phantom{+}(0000000)+(0001111)+(0110011)+(0111100)\\
+(1010101)+(1011010)+(1100110)+(1101001)
\end{align}$$

Is there an algorithm or method to calculate these kinds of simplexes?

Comment: Look up Hadamard matrices.  I think they only happen for dimensions $n=4k-1$.  Make the first column of the matrix all 1s, throw away the first column and you have 4k rows of n-vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but it's too long for a comment (EDIT - There is now an answer at the end).  I don't think this is possible.  I conjecture that there exists an $n$-simplex whose vertices have coordinates $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$ if and only if $n=2^k-1$ for some positive integer $k$.   I can prove the converse for now.  (See my edit at the end.  My conjecture is not true, but the proof below can be used to show that if an $n$-simplex with the required property exists, then a $(2n+1)$-simplex with the required property exists.)

Let $\oplus$ be the entry-wise addition modulo $2$.  For example $$(0,1,1,0)\oplus(1,0,1,0)=(1,1,0,0).$$  Define $h(x)$ for $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ to be the number of ones in $x$.  For example, $$h(0,0,1,1,1)=3.$$

For the converse, we prove inductively.  Let $x_0^k,x_1^k,\ldots,x_{2^k-1}^k$ be the vertices for a given $k$ such that $x_0^k=(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{2^k-1\ \text{zeros}})$, and each $x_i^k$ has exactly $2^{k-1}$ ones for $i=1,2,\ldots,2^k-1$.

We define the following vectors:
$$X_i^k=\left(0,x_i^k\right)$$
and
$$\bar{X}_i^k=(\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{2^k\ \text{ones}})\oplus  X_i^k.$$  Now take
$$x_{2i}^{k+1}=\left(x_i^k,X_i^k\right)$$
and
$$x_{2i+1}^{k+1}=\left(x_i^k,\bar{X}_i^k\right).$$
We have
\begin{align}h\left(x_{2i}^{k+1}\oplus x_{2i+1}^{k+1}\right)&=h\left(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{2^k-1\ \text{zeros}},\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{2^k\ \text{ones}}\right)=2^k.\end{align}
For $i\ne j$,
\begin{align}h\left(x_{2i}^{k+1}\oplus x_{2j}^{k+1}\right)&=h\left(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k,0,x_i^k\oplus x_j^k\right)\\&=2\cdot h(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k)=2\cdot2^{k-1}=2^k,\end{align}
\begin{align}h\left(x_{2i+1}^{k+1}\oplus x_{2j+1}^{k+1}\right)&=h\left(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k,0,x_i^k\oplus x_j^k\right)\\&=2\cdot h\left(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k\right)=2\cdot2^{k-1}=2^k,\end{align}
and
\begin{align}h\left(x_{2i}^{k+1}\oplus x_{2j+1}^{k+1}\right)&=h\left(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k,1,(\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{2^k-1\ \text{ones}})\oplus x_i^k\oplus x_j^k\right)\\&=h\left(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k\right)+2^k-h\left(x_i^k\oplus x_j^k\right)=2^k.\end{align}

For example, we start with $x_0^1=0$ and $x_1^1=1$.  Then we have
$$x_0^2=(0,0,0),x_1^2=(0,1,1),x_2^2=(1,0,1),x_3^2=(1,1,0).$$
Then
$$x_0^3=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0), x_1^3=(0,0,0,1,1,1,1),$$ $$x_2^3=(0,1,1,0,0,1,1),x_3^3=(0,1,1,1,1,0,0),$$
$$x_4^3=(1,0,1,0,1,0,1),x_5^3=(1,0,1,1,0,1,0),$$ $$x_6^3=(1,1,0,0,1,1,0),x_7^3=(1,1,0,1,0,0,1).$$

---

As remarked by Empy2, if there exists Hadamard matrix $H_{n+1}$ of size $(n+1)\times (n+1)$, then there exists such an $n$-simplex. If $H_{n+1}$ exists, we can assume that its first row and its first column are both $e=(\underbrace{1, 1, \ldots, 1}_{n+1\ \text{ones}})\in\Bbb R^{n+1}$.  Let $y_0,y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{n}\in\Bbb \{1,-1\}^{n+1}$ be the columns of $H_{n+1}$. Since $y_0=e$ is orthogonal to $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$, it follows that for $n>0$, $n$ must be odd and each $y_i$ has exactly $\frac{n+1}{2}$ ones for $i\ne 0$.

Define
$$X_i=\frac{1}{2}\big(e-y_i\big).$$
Then the first position of $X_i$ is always $0$.  We can take $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Bbb R^n$ to be
$$X_i=(0,x_i).$$
Then $x_0=(0,0,\ldots,0)$ and for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, $x_i$ has exactly $\frac{n+1}{2}$ ones.
 If $i\ne 0$, we have
$$h(x_0\oplus x_i)=h(x_i)=\frac{n+1}{2}.$$
If $i,j\ne 0$, we have
$$h(x_i\oplus x_j)=h(x_i)+h(x_j)-2x_i\cdot x_j=(n+1)-\frac12(e-y_i)\cdot(e-y_j).$$
Thus for $i,j\ne 0$ and $i\ne j$, we get
$$h(x_i\oplus x_j)=(n+1)-\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2}.$$
This means $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ form an $n$-simplex.

I think the converse holds too.  That is, I have the following conjecture.  I guess that if $h(x_i)=\delta$ for $i\ne 0$, then we can assume wlog that $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2\delta-1}$ *live* in $\mathbb{R}^{2\delta-1}$.  The "wlog" assumption cannot yet be shown that it is indeed "wlog".

> **Conjecture:**  An $n$-simplex whose vertices are $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\{0,1\}^n$ exists if and only if a Hadamard matrix of size $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ exists.

It is [conjectured](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardMatrix.html) that $H_{n+1}$ exists iff $n=0$, $n=1$, or $n=4k-1$ for some positive integer $k$. (The forward implication is known and not difficult to prove.  That is, if $H_{n+1}$ exists, then $n=0$, $n=1$, or $n=4k-1$.  See page 6 [here](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/hadamard.pdf).)  The conjecture is true at least for $n\le 100$.  Therefore at least for $n\le 100$ and $n=4k-1$, you can find your $n$-simplex.

---

For the situation at hand ($n=5$), such a simplex doesn't exist.  Suppose for contradiction that $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in\{0,1\}^5$ exist so that $h(x_i\oplus x_j)=\delta$ for some fixed integer $\delta$.  WLOG, $x_0=(0,0,0,0,0)$.

Note that $h(x_i)=h(x_i\oplus x_0)=\delta$ for $i\ne 0$.  Therefore,
$$\delta=h(x_i\oplus x_j)=h(x_i)+h(x_j)-2x_i\cdot x_j=2\delta-2x_i\cdot x_j.$$
This means
$$\delta=2x_i\cdot x_j.$$
Hence $\delta$ is even.  Write $\delta=2d$.  Clearly, there are only two possible cases: $d=1$ or $d=2$.

If $d=2$, then $\delta=4$.  There are exactly $5$ vectors in $\{0,1\}^5$ with $4$ ones:
$$(0,1,1,1,1),(1,0,1,1,1),(1,1,0,1,1),(1,1,1,0,1),(1,1,1,1,0).$$
This means
$$h(x_i\oplus x_j)=2\ne\delta$$
for $i,j\ne 0$ and $i\ne j$.  So $d\ne 2$.

If $d=1$, then $\delta=2$.  Wlog, we can take
$$x_1=(0,0,0,1,1)\wedge x_2=(0,0,1,0,1).$$
Now, it follows that there is only one choice left for $x_3,x_4,x_5$, which is $(0,0,1,1,0)$.  We have a contradiction again.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This clarifies what I need to do. I'm trying to find this simplex to use it as the states of a quantum error-correction code, so in order to use these coordenates as equiprobable states of qubits they need to assume only values of 0 and1

Comment: @Nillmer Can you embed the system into a $6$-dimensional space instead?  It is possible to do this in $6$ dimensions.  Take $(000001)$, $(000010)$, $(000100)$, $(001000)$, $(010000)$, and $(100000)$.  This can be done for any $n$-simplex, not just $n=5$.

Comment: I don't think so, because error-correction codes can't have an even number of qubits, because then your system can't do parity checks properly.

Comment: @Nillmer I see.  That's tough because I really believe that it is impossible after some attempts.  I just can't prove it yet.

Comment: The codes that use simplexes are called Hamming codes, I was trying to make a similar code with a differente method.

Comment: @Nillmer I see.  Good luck.  Since no proof has come out, my conjecture may still be false.

Comment: I'll keep the question live and talk to some people I know that might know it better than me. But you gave me a few ideas for other paths to follow, thank you so much!

Comment: @Nillmer, I have at least answered your question for $n=5$.  If you want to accept my answer, at least your question has been completely answered (I will not object if you do so).  However, I would prefer that my answer remains unaccepted until somebody could fill in the last blank.  (I'd like to know if highlighted conjecture is true.)